# Javascript values not being assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am having a problem getting values assigned for `fname`, `lname` and etc, these do not exist on the page until the success function is called and it posts to `template/orderForm.php`. if i for example `console.log(fname)` i get an empty field.

The first thing that happens is on login button submit it checks the information against the database via phpscripts/login.php, on success of that it posts to another page to get form data, such as their name and etc which are auto-populated with php echos.

```
$("#loginSubmit").click(function() {
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpscripts/login.php",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    },
    success: function(data){
      if(data == 'worked') {
        $("#loginForm").hide(500);
        $("#loginBtn").hide(500);
        $("#registerBtn").hide(500);
        $("#forgotPasswordBtn").hide(500);
        $.post('template/orderForm.php', function(data) {
          $('#approveData').html(data);
          $("#updateInfo").click(function() {
            var fname = $('#fname').attr('value');
            var lname = $('#lname').attr('value');
            var address = $('#address').attr('value');
            var city = $('#city').attr('value');
            var state = $('#state').attr('value');
            var zip = $('#zip').attr('value');
            var phone = $('#phone').attr('value');
            console.log(fname);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              //change to update script that is in myaccount.php
              url: "phpscripts/update.php",
              data: {
                fname: fname,
                lname: lname,
                address: address,
                city: city,
                state: state,
                zip: zip,
                phone: phone
              },
              success: function(){
                //do nothing
              }

            });
          });
        });


      }
      else {

      }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using $('#fname').val() in that updateInfo click listener? (btw it would help to see the html as well)

Comment: A tip: you don't need `else` if there's nothing else...

Comment: I figured out the problem, there are multiple IDs that are fname, lname and etc on this page, i didn't see them at first because they are across multiple php includes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#fname').val()` instead of `$('#fname').attr('value')`, and same with others.

Comment: i have tried it with $('#fname').val() and $('#fname').prop('value')

Comment: @Jeff You should use `.val()` to access the value, the use input won't change the attribute `value`'s content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on with your HTML so here's my guess:

This line:

```
$('#approveData').html(data);
```

contains your html which houses the element with an id of fname.

This js:

```
$("#updateInfo").click(function() { ... });
```

should be this:

```
$("#updateInfo").live('click', function() { ... });
```

And be outside in a ready statement or something. Not defined within the results of another listener.

This link explains .live:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

It registers newly inserted dom elements where as your basic listener you provided will not IF the fname element is written in by your request - an assumption, so don't yell if I am wrong here.

Comment: The `.click(function(){})` and `.on('click',function(){})` syntaxes you show are equivalent. Were you trying to recommend delegated event handling as for one of the other syntaxes of `.on()`?

Comment: You're right, if I am recalling correctly now - .live is what I think I was referring to since click will be converted to on('click' automatically anyhow... but OP says he solved so I suppose this is now irrelevant

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated - `.on()` can do the same thing that `.live()` did if you pass it the right parameters. The jQuery doco covers the details.